# Issue running file from within NeoVim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype-c++

I had the following remap

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F5> :w <bar> silent !g++ -ulimit -Wall -Wno-unused-result -std=c++11   -O2   % -o %:r && %:r<CR>
```

When I run this in Vim, a terminal like this shows up
[image: vim output]

But in Neovim, I get this
[image: neovim output]

If I have 2 remaps, one for compiling and one for running, I get shell returned with 139.
I want to get the above functionality in Neovim.

These are the commands that I used

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F9> :w <bar> !mkdir -p .outputs && g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wshadow -Wall % -o .outputs/%:r -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG<CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F12> :!.outputs/%:r<CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F5> :w <bar> !g++ -ulimit -Wall -Wno-unused-result -std=c++11   -O2   % -o %:r && %:r<CR>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you're just typing `nameofthexecutable` in the console. It's the same for Vim, the path to that executable is required if it isn't in `$PATH` ==> `./nameofthexecutable`

---

Otherwise, we have a better user experience in Vim to compile C++ when we use the quickfix feature. In particular when there are hundred of error lines because we are sending an object to `std::cout` and have forgotten to overload the `operator<<` for its type.

Unless your flavour of `make` is incorrectly configured, there is no need to play with `&makeprg`, we can keep it simple and just set `$CXXFLAGS`, `$LDFLAGS` and `$LDLIBS`, `make` will take care of everything for single file programs.

```
" ~/.vimrc
filetype plugin on


" ~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim
" ftplugins are easier to maintain when there are several definitions
let $CXXFLAGS = '-ulimit -Wall -Wno-unused-result -std=c++11 -O2'

" - don't forget <buffer> for ft-specific mappings
" - using the quickfix feature for vim really make the difference when compiling C++
" - I use a trick to inject the execution at the end of the execution
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <F5> :<c-u>w <bar> :make %< && ./%<
```

However, there is a little issue to chain compilation and execution. Either we use the little trick I've used just above, or we add a missing feature. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991040/15934

Comment: No. I've tested it this way. I have the same vimrc set up both for neovim and vim. It works in vim but not in neovim

My init.vim: [https://pastebin.com/ZrgGajG0](https://pastebin.com/ZrgGajG0)


FYI: The autocommands are in the end

Comment: By _"tested this way"_? You mean you've tested the 3 points I've suggested: with an explicit path to the executable, and the quickfix feature, and with an ftplugin to avoid poor side effects from direct use of autocommands?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I am saying the same vimrc works as shown in vim but doesn't work the same way as vim in nvim. The problem was me expecting the same terminal from both vim and nvim. Can you please expand on your answer as to what you meant by the ftplugin/cpp.vim.. I am a newbie to vim and nvim

Comment: (Indirectly) Using the terminal as you are doing is what we had to do with Vi. Not Vim. Vi! Vim provides (from the very beginning) a way to integrate compilation. See `:h :make`. If you follow the link I gave you'll have explanations. Regarding _ftplugin_, they are a dedicated mechanism since Vim 6.0 to define filetype related things (mappings, etc). `:h filetype` for more. I gave the minimum required code snippets for your `~/.vimrc` (or neovim equivalent), and a simplified content for `~/ftplugin/cpp.vim`. Autocommands are the low level feature, that have some side-effects sometimes.

Comment: I set it up the way you said now. The problem I have now is I am not able to interact with it. I want to run the executable the way it runs in a terminal(it should receive inputs and be interactive). I am sorry, I am a newbie

Comment: I understand your answer properly now. I understand that you ask to use make instead of running the g++ command directly. Yes, now the make works. The issue that I have now is I want to be able to give input to the executable file and I am not able to do that from within vim. How should I got about this?

Comment: You can run your executable with `:term ./%` -- I usually separate compilation from execution. But if you really want it, a little work is required, see the link I've provided in order to prevent execution is compilation fails.